# Hiding header isn't working - Django ecommerce

Tags: javascript, navbar

I have a header I want to hide when scrolling down. The header is located in my templates folder in Django, file name is base.html - see code below:

```
 <body>
    <header class="container-fluid fixed-top">
        <div id="topnav" class="row pt-lg-2 d-none d-lg-flex">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 my-auto py-1 py-lg-0">
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="logo-homepage">
                    <img src="/media/logo.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="logo">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 my-auto py-1 py-lg-0">
                <form method="GET" action="{% url 'products' %}">
                    <div class="input-group w-100">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for your vinyl" name="search" 
                            aria-label="search_vinyl" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="button-addon2">
                                <span class="search-vinyl"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 my-auto py-1 py-lg-0">
                <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled text-center text-lg-right my-0">
                    <li class="list-inline-item dropdown px-5 nav-item-bg">
                        <a class="text-black nav-link" href="#" id="user-options" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <div><i class="fas fa-user fa-lg"></i></div>
                                <p class="my-0">My Account</p>
                            </div>    
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu border-0" aria-labelledby="user-options">
                            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                                {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                                    <a href="{% url 'add_product' %}" class="dropdown-item">Product Management</a>
                                {% endif %}
                                <a href="{% url 'profile' %}" class="dropdown-item">My Profile</a>
                                <a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}" class="dropdown-item">Log Out</a>
                            {% else %}
                                <a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}" class="dropdown-item">Sign Up</a>
                                <a href="{% url 'account_login' %}" class="dropdown-item">Log In</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item px-5 nav-item-bg">
                        <a class="{% if grand_total %}text-info{% else %}text-black{% endif %} nav-link"
                            href="{% url 'view_bag' %}">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <div><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag fa-lg"></i></div>
                                <p class="my-0">
                                    {% if grand_total %}
                                        £{{ grand_total|floatformat:2 }}
                                    {% else %}
                                        £0.00
                                    {% endif %}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light w-100">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav"
                    aria-controls="main-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                {% include 'includes/mobile-top-header.html' %}
                {% include 'includes/main-nav.html' %}
            </nav>
        </div>    
    </header>

    {% if messages %}
    <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <p class="mb-0">
            {% for message in messages %}
                {% with message.level as level %}
                    {% if level == 40 %}
                        {% include 'includes/toasts/toast_error.html' %}
                    {% elif level == 30 %}
                        {% include 'includes/toasts/toast_warning.html' %}
                    {% elif level == 25 %}
                        {% include 'includes/toasts/toast_success.html' %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% include 'includes/toasts/toast_info.html' %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
    </blockquote>
    {% endif %}

    {% block page_header %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}


    {% block postloadjs %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.toast').toast('show');
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lastScrollTop;
        navbar = document.getElementsByClassName('fixed-top');
        window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
        var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if(scrollTop > lastScrollTop){
        navbar.style.top='-80px';
        }
        else{
        navbar.style.top='0';
        }
        lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
        });
    </script>
    {% endblock %}

</body>
```

The script I have tried to hide the header is as it follows (it's also above in the first snippet I have shared):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var lastScrollTop;
        navbar = document.getElementsByClassName('fixed-top');
        window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
        var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if(scrollTop > lastScrollTop){
        navbar.style.top='-80px';
        }
        else{
        navbar.style.top='0';
        }
        lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
        });
    </script>
```

I am getting the following error:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'top')*

Could anyone tell me what I am missing please?
Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, not the single one. You have to traverse this collection to access every single element:

```
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('fixed-top');
  for( let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ )
    elements[i].style.top = 0;
```

Comment: Hi Jared. I eventually used jQuery to solve it:                                                                                   
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).scroll(function (e) {
            var $el = $('header');

            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                $('header').css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });
            }
            if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
                $('header').css({
                    'display': 'block'
                });
            }
        });
    </script>